# assetic and url rewriting

Tags: symfony, iis, url-rewriting, assetic

Hi i need to put on prod a website made with symfony2. I use IIS (microsoft server ) 
I have a problem when loading the assetic files because IIS needs this url rewriting rule :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Otherwise , it is looking in the folders, instead of getting the routes.

But now assetic is searching for routes too!!
When i open a css file :

> GET route css/.. has not been found.

well the standard error GET not found ; the url rewriting is also making its work on my assetic files...

Basically i need to create a rule which ignores css/ paths so i put the rule

```
^css/*    ( also tried ^css/ )
```

with action type : "nothing" but it doesn't seem to work

thanks for your help

Comment: Have you installed or dumped the assets? *it is looking in the folders* Who is looking?

Comment: thanks for your answer , i found my way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add 3 conditions {PATH_INFO}, type "doesn't fit the model", with css, js, and images as models.